# Firebase:Issue with adding compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)' dependencier

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My app is working okey byt when I add  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)' to add firebase custom outh

The error works in this code,

```
public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }

        }
}
Error:(23, 25) error: method getApps in class FirebaseApp cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: Application
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length............,
```

and also this warning.

```
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the firebase server SDK. You need to import the Android version.

Follow the Android tutorial at https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Comment: Good catch! You should never run the custom authentication code in the client app. Creating a custom token requires access to your app's secret, which should never be exposed in client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its self-evident from the error message that your method FirebaseApp.getApp() does not need any argument.

Try changing the code to:

```
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    if (!FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }

    }
}
```

Check getApp() documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_getDefaultConfig)